# how to handle received TCP packets in socket programming C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a txt file that is 150kb. and i want to send it via socket programming and in a custom way:

I want to send first 136160 bytes through port x and 13840 bytes through another port (port y).

At the destination it also receives the first 136160 bytes but **drops** the next 13840 bytes.

In fact, I want this packet dropping to be **dynamic** so for each file we can individually specify how many bytes should be dropped.

I have the sender part of code and really in need of the codes in receiver part.

Thanks in advance for your answers and assistance

here is the normal codes of receiver which i use:

```
           public void Listen(){



        Socket SoListen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPEndPoint IPE = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(txtPort.Text));

        SoListen.Bind(IPE);

        SoListen.Listen(2);

        Socket CGetFile = SoListen.Accept();



        byte[] bfile = new byte[1024 * 1000000];

        while (true)

        {

            int r = CGetFile.Receive(bfile);

            if (r > 0)

            {

                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>

                {

                    lblStatus.Text = "recieving";

                    SaveFileDialog SD = new SaveFileDialog();

                    if (SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                    {

                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(SD.FileName, FileMode.Create);

                        fs.Write(bfile, 0, r);

                        fs.Flush();

                        lblStatus.Text = "recieved";



                    }



                }));

                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();

            }

        }





    }
```

Comment: If you're new to socket programming, I'd first get some experience with the regular transfer of data using sockets, before trying something custom like this. There are plenty tutorials out there. If you _do_ have experience with socket programming, you can probably ask a more specific question.

Comment: yeah, i don't have any exprience and this question is a challenge in my work and i got in trouble with hat for a few months...:(((

Comment: Given that you don't provide any code and don't ask a specific implementation problem you are basically ask others to provide the full code for the receiver. This is not how this site works: it is about helping users with __specific__ problems and not write code for others. Maybe hire somebody for this.

Comment: `really in need of the codes`.... says it all, really.

Comment: yeah, i have the code but i did not insert that